# How to add script to React component and use as constructor function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, webm

I'm trying to load external javascript (https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js) to my React.js component.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
let aScript = document.createElement('script');
aScript.type = 'text/javascript';
aScript.src = "CCapture.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(aScript);
```

This code correctly appends script to the page (checked the HTML).
But now I'm wondering how can I use the contents of the script in a constructor function. Specifically, per the documentation - it would look something like this..

```
var capturer = new CCapture({
    framerate: 60,
    verbose: true
});
```

The error I'm getting says the CCapture is not defined. Am I missing something here? Not sure how to pull from the library itself.

I've added a function to make sure it is loading before the function itself runs per this instruction, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848407/8497330.

I'm also *not* using the npm package because it does not work for the 'webm' format. Looking for a bandaid while the npm package is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

First of You should load your script asynchronously. For instance, you can use this gist: [loadScript](https://gist.github.com/james2doyle/28a59f8692cec6f334773007b31a1523).
This `loadScript` function returns a promise which you can use to wait for your library to load.
Secondly, you should not put your code inside the constructor and instead in the `componentDidMount` like this

```
componentDidMount () {
    loadScript('CCapture.min.js')
      .then(() => {
        var capturer = new CCapture({
          framerate: 60,
          verbose: true
        });
      })
      // you can even handle the loading error for your script
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error when loading CCapture.min.js: ', error);
      });
}
```

In cae you need it you could aslo save the `capturer` instance in your component state (using `this.setState({capturer})`) or directly inside the instance object of your component like `this.capturer = capturer;`

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that the script hasn't been loaded and evaluated by the browser before you're making your call. The is an excellent (and detailed) description of what is happening in this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786759/105518

In my experience, the last piece of advice in that answer is generally the least painful to implement: leverage JQuery's `getScript` function. It handles wiring up all the bits for you:

```
$.getScript("CCapture.min.js", function () {
    const capturer = new CCapture({
        framerate: 60,
        verbose: true
    });
});
```