# Using Vidyard embedded player inside of React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I've been tasked with inserting an embedded "Vidyard" video into a React project.

The embed code looks something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async 
  src="https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js">
</script>
<img
  style="width: 100%; margin: auto; display: block;"
  class="vidyard-player-embed"
  src="xxxx"
  data-uuid="xxxx"
  data-v="4"
  data-type="inline"
/>
```

This does not work 100% of the time.
When I insert this into a plain `.html` file, the video shows up.

On the plain `.html` file, the image loads and I believe the script then finds the image and drops the embedded video player on the DOM from there.

What I believe is happening is that there is a conflict between React/Vidyard as far as manipulating the DOM.

I've attempted to drop this directly into a component with no luck.
I've also added the script call directly to the `<head>`.
I've followed [Script load in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847126/script-load-in-react) and attempted to manually call the script file, I also stuck the manual script load in both the `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`.
I've also inserted the code into `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

The behavior remains the same.

Ideally if this was to work the image would append to the page. The `embed/v4.js` script would then append a embedded video player on the image. Currently, the image appears and does not get switched out to a video. If i refresh/hard refresh the page, sometimes the image will swap out for the embedded video player.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution for those who prefer hooks/functional components:

```
import React from "react"
import ScriptLoader from "react-script-loader-hoc"

const VIDYARD_EMBED_JS_URL = "https://play.vidyard.com/embed/v4.js"

function VidyardPlayer(props: {
  scriptsLoadedSuccessfully: boolean
  maxWidth: string
  maxHeight: string
  type: string
  uuid: string
  aspect?: "4:3" | "16:9" | "16:10"
  onLoadCallback?: (player: any, embedApi: any) => void
}) {
  const {
    scriptsLoadedSuccessfully,
    maxWidth,
    maxHeight,
    type,
    uuid,
    aspect,
    onLoadCallback,
  } = props
  const containerRef = React.useRef<any>()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (scriptsLoadedSuccessfully) {
      window.VidyardV4.api
        .renderPlayer({
          aspect,
          container: containerRef.current,
          height: maxHeight,
          type,
          uuid,
          width: maxWidth,
        })
        .then((player: any) => {
          if (onLoadCallback) {
            onLoadCallback(player, window.VidyardV4.api)
          }
        })
        .catch((e: any) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.error(e.message)
        })
    }
  }, [scriptsLoadedSuccessfully])

  return <div ref={containerRef} />
}

export default ScriptLoader(VIDYARD_EMBED_JS_URL)(VidyardPlayer)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution for the same problem. Here's the player component that you can import and just pass the video id.

```
/* eslint-disable */
import * as React from 'react';

let vidyardEmbed = {};
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  vidyardEmbed = require('../../../utils/vidyard');
}

export default class VidyardEmbed extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
    this.handleContainerRef = ref => {
      if (ref) {
        this.container = ref;
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.container) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.props.playbackUrl) {
      vidyardEmbed._debug.setPlaybackURL(this.props.playbackUrl);
    }
    vidyardEmbed.api
      .renderPlayer(
        Object.assign(
          {
            aspect: this.props.aspect,
            container: this.container,
            height: this.props.maxHeight,
            type: this.props.type,
            uuid: this.props.uuid,
            width: this.props.maxWidth
          },
          this.props.params
        )
      )
      .then(player => {
        this.player = player;
        if (typeof this.props.api === 'function') {
          this.props.api(player, vidyardEmbed.api);
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.setState({ hasError: true });
        console.warn(e.message);
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.player) {
      vidyardEmbed.api.destroyPlayer(this.player);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.handleContainerRef} />;
  }
}
```

The imported vidyard file is the script that they offer but I imported it locally. That way I was able to get it working within React without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

try running this after the page is loaded:

```
vidyardEmbed.api.renderDOMPlayers();
```

You can find more information how vidyard works here:
https://developer.vidyard.com/responsive-player-embed-api.html